# ActiveRecord detect setting of the attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Say, I have a model `A` with attribute `name`.

If I do this `A.new(name: nil).name_changed?`, it will return `false`.

How can I detect that the attribute was set, even if it change nothing?

Comment: Instead of checking that the name was changed, why don't you check if the name is nil?

Comment: if it is nil I have to set it some value, but if it was **set** nil I have to validate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name_set

  def name=(v)
    @name_set = true
    super(v)
  end
end
```

Now you can query the object with the `name_set` method.

Comment: yeah, I thought about this, but I have to manually create the methods. I just thought rails have built-in methods for that